# Windows 10 to go on partition of external usb drive

Tags: windows, macos, partitioning, external-hard-drive, windows-to-go

I have an external drive with a free partition and all I want is creating a "windows 10 to go" on it so I can boot on this partition to run a live version of windows 10. Nonetheless, I only found answers about a windows to go for the entreprise version of windows 8. So is there a way to install a live version of windows 10 on a partition of an external USB drive ?

I only have 2 macs at my disposal.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to install Windows 10 to an USB external HDD or SSD for use on single computer? Or, are you asking how to install Windows 10 to Go on a "Windows to Go certified" USB drive for use on any computer?

Comment: A windows 10 to go on one of the partitions of my external USB drive :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a Windows system, then you can use [WinToUSB](https://easyuefi.com/wintousb/) to do it. I've just successfully used it to install Windows 10 Pro to my own external drive and it works fine on my iMac.